# Breaking cyclic dependency in Dagger

Tags: dagger, cyclic-dependency

*I am very new to dagger--I don't even know yet if it will work for my application*

I have a search page that returns the latest news about a given celebrity.

I have written a test to verify that results appear on the page when we search for a popular celebrity.

The `page` has a `searchField`, which requires `page` in its constructor so the web driver I use for my tests can select it.

**Celebrity Search Page Test**

```
public class CelebritySearchPageTest {
    @Test
    public void testSearchResultsForKevinBaconVerifyHisPopularity() {
        CelebritySearchPage searchPage = new CelebritySearchPage();
        searchPage.searchFor("Kevin Bacon");
        Assert.assertTrue(searchPage.getNumberOfResults() > 9999999, "Verify that Kevin Bacon is still relevant");
    }
}
```

**Celebrity Search Page**

```
public class CelebritySearchPage extends Page {
    @Inject
    @Named("search field")
    TextField searchField;

    public void searchFor(String text) {
        searchField.setText(text);
        // ...
    }

    public int getNumberOfResults() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Celebrity Search Page Module**

```
@Module(injects = CelebritySearchPage.class)
public class CelebritySearchPageModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("search field")
    public TextField provideSearchField() {
        return new TextField(/* How do I get the page? */, "#searchField");
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
public abstract class Page {
    // ...
}
```

**Text Field**

```
public class TextField {
    protected Page page;
    protected String selector;

    public TextField(Page page, String selector) {
        this.page = page;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that `page` needs `searchField`, but `searchField` needs `page`. How do I get over this cyclic dependency?

*I can't initialize `searchField` inside of CelebritySearchPage*

Comment: why does TextField need Page?

Comment: @AndreasFrische `textField.getFullSelector()` calls `page.getFullSelector()`

Comment: ok. Maybe inject a FullSelectorHolder then. Or Use Lazy:
"Sometimes you need an object to be instantiated lazily. For any binding T, you can create a Lazy<T> which defers instantiation until the first call to Lazy<T>'s get() method."

Comment: @AndreasFrische Can you add an answer showing how you would use the Lazy method? It sounds promising. I'll accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

CelebritySearchPage

```
public class CelebritySearchPage extends Page {
    private final Lazy<TextField> searchField;
// always prefer constructor injection
// avoid @Named if possible, since the compiler cannot check the string
    @Inject
    CelebritySearchPage(@Named("search field") Lazy<TextField> searchField) {
        this.searchField = searchField; 
    }
}
```

Text Field

```
public class TextField {
    protected final Lazy<Page> page;
    protected final String selector;

    @Inject TextField(Lazy<Page> page, String selector) {
        this.page = page;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

/*
Lazy::get()
Return the underlying value, computing the value if necessary. All calls to      the same Lazy instance will return the same result.
*/
}
```

I guess one Lazy should suffice as well.

Comment: How do I then construct `CelebritySearchPage` because `TextField` and `CelebritySearchPage` require one another in their constructor.

Comment: Don't construct. Inject.

Comment: How do I inject? Can you show an example of using the page without constructing it?

Comment: to be honest, read the fine manual. Start here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies#break-the-cycle-with-a-provider